# Financial agricultural data for Chile's different regions

Tags: data-request, agriculture, chile

I am trying to find financial agricultural data for Chile, not as a whole country but for its regions.

I found data on [FAOSTAT](https://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data/QV) for Chile as a whole country but want more detailed data.

Comment: Open data platform of the Chilean government http://datos.gob.cl